# DRF: why do accesses redirect to /login/ when 'AllowAny' is used?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework and a Class Based View derived from APIView. I've set the permissions to 'AllowAny' but I always get redirect to the `/login/` URL when I try to access `/api/foo/`

```
class FooList(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        foos = Foo.objects.all()
        serializer = FooSerializer(foos, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = FooSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I've set the `REST_FRAMEWORK` as follows :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
}
```

but still it happens.

This is what a request looks like :

```
(httppie)rshea@polo ~/dev/djangodrfts $ http  --json --verbose http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/foo/
GET /api/foo/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.3



HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 06 Mar 2016 10:46:28 GMT
Location: /foo/login?next=/api/foo/
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Any suggestions as to why the `AllowAny` seems to be forcing a login ?

Comment: What do your urls file looks like ?

Comment: @Linovia : thank you very much ! Your question made me review the urls.py and I realised that I had defined two CBV's with the same name. One of them was a sub-class of 'APIView' and the other was a sub-class of 'TemplateView'. The second one required that you logon before accessing it and so when I did a GET via the API trying to use the 'APIView' one I actually ended up trying to get the 'TemplateView' one which resulted in me being asked to logon ! If you want to flesh out your comment as an answer I will be happy to mark it correct. Thanks again.